OSError(22, 'Invalid argument') - cannot open any `.ipynb` and `.py` file
I am unable to open any of my past Jupyernotebook or python files I have and I get this error for them:
Unreadable Notebook: C:\Users\[mypath]\main\main.ipynb OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')

[mypath] is the part of directory I deleted from above here.
I tried solution by this post, but still have the same issue.
This is also the error I get opening a .py file
Error! Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
result = await result
File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\handlers.py", line 111, in get
model = yield maybe_future(self.contents_manager.get(
File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 444, in get
model = self._file_model(path, content=content, format=format)
File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\filemanager.py", line 371, in
_file_model
content, format = self._read_file(os_path, format)
File "C:\Users\moham\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\fileio.py", line 306, in
_read_file
bcontent = f.read()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Same issue persists opening the files via jupyterlab.

Have you tried restarting your computer?

@nneonneo, yes and still the same issue.

Are you able to open those files in any other program (such as a text editor)? Have you tried checking the file permissions, and checking your hard drive for errors?
